# Test that $timeout was called only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, timeout

I have the following controller:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('MyCtrl', function ($timeout) {
    var self = this;

    var currentNumber = 0;
    var isBusy = false;

    self.items = [];
    self.loadMore = function () {
        if (isBusy) {
            return;
        }

        isBusy = true;

        $timeout(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                self.items.push(currentNumber);
                currentNumber++;
            }

            isBusy = false;
        }, 1000);
    };
});
```

It exposes the `loadMore` method which add elements to `items` after one second. During that second, a flag `isBusy` is set to true, so that if you call `loadMore` while `isBusy` is true, nothing else happen.

I would like to test that even if I call `loadMore` twice, `$timeout` is called once.

Here is the jasmine test:

```
describe('MyCtrl', function () {
    var ctrl,
        timeout;

    beforeEach(module('myapp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $timeout) {
        timeout = $timeout;
        ctrl = $controller('SelectionCtrl', {$timeout: timeout});
    }));

    it('$timeout should be called once when calling loadMore multiple times', function () {
        ctrl.loadMore();
        ctrl.loadMore();

        // TODO verify that $timeout was called once
    });
});
```

I know that I have use a spy, but `$timeout` is a function, and doesn't provides a method to spy on.

How can I achieve this ? Thank you.

Comment: why don't you expose isBusy with a getter ?